# Is it possible to auto generate Getter/Setter from Array Values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, getter-setter

So I have a couple of arrays

```
$array_1 = Array('one','two','three');
$array_2 = Array('red','blue','green');
```

Is there a dynamic way to create the Setters and Getters for an array with single value entries?

So the class would be something like:

```
class xFromArray() {

}
```

So the above if I passed $array_1 it would generate something like this:

```
private $one;

setOne($x) {
   $one = $x;
}

getOne() {
   return $one;
}
```

if I passed $array_2 it would generate something like this:

```
private $red;

setRed($x) {
   $red = $x;
}

getRed() {
   return $red;
}
```

So I would call it somehow like this? (My best guess but doesn't seem that this would work)

```
$xFromArray = new xFromArray;
foreach($array_1 as $key=>$data) {
   $xFromArray->create_function(set.ucfirst($data)($data));
   echo $xFromArray->create_function(get.ucfirst($data));
}
```

Comment: That sounds ugly, doesn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `__call()` to invoke dynamic methods. So:

```
class Wrapper {
  private $properties;

  public function __construct(array $names) {
    $this->properties = array_combine(array_keys($names),
      array_fill(0, count($names), null));
  }

  public function __call($name, $args) {
    if (preg_match('!(get|set)(\w+)!', $name, $match)) {
      $prop = lcfirst($match[2]);
      if ($match[1] == 'get') {
        if (count($args) != 0) {
          throw new Exception("Method '$name' expected 0 arguments, got " . count($args));
        }
        return $properties[$prop];
      } else {
        if (count($args) != 1) {
          throw new Exception("Method '$name' expected 1 argument, got " . count($args));
        }
        $properties[$prop] = $args[0];
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Unknown method $name");
    }
  }
}
```

Personally I wouldn't go the route of using getters and setters in PHP. Use the special methods `__get()` and `__set()` instead and treat these dynamic properties as object properties rather than adding a (most likely unnecessary) method wrapper.

**Edit:** to clarify, `__call()` is invoked when you call an method in an object that either doesn't exist or is inaccessible. So:

```
$wrapper = new Wrapper($array_1);
$wrapper->setOne("foo");
echo $wrapper->getOne(); // foo
$wrapper->getAbc(); // exception, property doesn't exist
```

`__call()` is used here to decipher the method name. If it fits the pattern of get or set followed by a property name (from the initial array) then it works as expected, otherwise it throws an exception. You can of course change this behaviour any way you wish.

See [Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) from the PHP manual for a more detailed explanation of these "magic" methods.

Comment: This is how I would call it: $wrapper = new Wrapper($array_1); How do I call the individual values from the array in the Set/Get wrapper?

Comment: would it be $wrapper->__call($name, 'get');

Comment: It would be as you described: for item 'one' you'd call `$wrapper->setOne('some value');` & to get it `$wrapper->getOne();`

Comment: While this works, it is full of boilerplate cruft. As an alternative, you might be interested in checking out: https://github.com/metaphp/attributes

Answer (score 2):

You can use __call() (or  __set() && __get()), but they have some overhead.